# Could not load data for the Visual in Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI Service visual for one of my calculated column is not getting loaded. It is giving the following error:

***"The query referenced calculated column 'RequestCountPerUser'[HourTime] which does not hold any data because evaluation of one of the rows caused an error."***

Here, HourTime is the calculated column that basically calculate the Time from the TimeStamp column.

**Note: The visual works in Power Bi desktop when Model is refreshed. The issue is pertinent only to the Power BI Service. Even in Power Bi Service the Visual works when the Model is published, the issue appears when the Model is refreshed.**

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be possibly introducing NULL or blank volumes in the column your HourTime is referencing upon refresh?

Comment: No Timestamp column is a DateTime column and it does not contain any null or blank value. Since, everything works as expected in Power BI Desktop but not in Power BI Service. I am not able to figure out what might be the possible issue.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, were you able to find the solution to this? I am facing the same issue.